# Are there javax.sound interfaces for libsox or libsndfile?

Tags: java, audio, caf, libsndfile

I'm looking to open/manipulate CAF (Core Audio Format) files from a Java application that already uses javax.sound to do its work. Does anybody know of a javax.sound wrapper for libsox or libsndfile, each of which support CAF natively?

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure those things don't exist. Maybe this will work, though: http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/